# Rails: Reference an engine from an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-engines

I have a higher level app, that includes two engines:

- Core (engine)
- API (engine)

The API engine depends on the models present in the Core engine. I was wondering how to reference these.

---

**What I have tried**

For example, if the Core engine has the model "User", how do I reference it via the API engine?

```
module Api
describe User do
routes { Api::Engine.routes }

before :each do
  ::Core::User.create!
end
....
```

With this code, I received:

```
 Failure/Error: ::Core::User.create!
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Core
```

So I thought that I had to include the core engine in the api.gemspec file.

```
  s.add_dependency "core", path: "core/"
```

however, looks like bundler did not like that.

```
There was a Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError while loading
api.gemspec:
Illformed requirement [{:path=>"core/"}] from myAppPath/api/api.gemspec:21:in
```

I also tried

```
s.add_dependency "core", path: "../core/"
```

but that gave me a similar error.

Any idea what should be done to reference the `Core` models from the `API` engine?

Thanks!

**Update**
I attempted to add the Core engine into the Api engine via the Api's Gemfile. Unfortunately, I get an error. I'm starting to feel that engine's should not reference other engines. Would that be true?

```
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-
4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated': 
Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to 
updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #
<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007fb53b67bce8 @paths=
["/home/myApp/api/spec/dummy/config/routes.rb", "/home/myApp/core/config/routes.rb", 
"/home/myApp/api/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#
<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fb53b3b8420>, #
<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fb53b6008b8>, #
<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fb53b6b9b60>]> (RuntimeError)
```

---

**UPDATE on findings**
In addition to the answer below, I would like to add that .gemspec files DO NOT have any information on where the gem will be stored, i.e. it will not point to a git repository, or a file path, etc. This is explained in this article:

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/

Comment: add it to your API's gem file like gem "core", path: "path/to/core/".

Comment: as in to the Gemfile? yeah, I think that may be the way. I just tried that - got a different error, but I have a feeling this new error is unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things to understand here:

If your Engines are supposed to be public (like Devise engine for example), then you'll want to reference your `Core` dependency in the `gemspec`. You'll not be able to reference it using `path` though. But for public engines, this is not a matter since public engines will be on Rubygems at some point in time.

If your Engines are private and used only to cleanup your code base, then adding `gem 'core', path: '../core'` to your Engine's Gemfile is fine.

The thing to remember here:

- `gemspec` is for dependencies declaration (the gems your engine needs in order to work)
- `Gemfile` is for local or test dependencies declaration

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer. I have a full blown 'app' rails app, and a 'api' engine, and a 'core' engine that lives under the 'app'. The 'api' depends on the 'core' engine, so would I have to add 'core' in the api.gemspec? If that's the case, I couldnt get it to work.

Comment: Both 'api' and 'core' gems are private, so I haven't published them on Rubygems (and hence I would need to use a path, but looks like a *.gemspec doesn't like paths ...)

Comment: btw - I added the core into my Gemfile, but as soon as I do that, I get some error. Any idea what it may be?